# Why is my expression for current I(2) wrong?

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws, ohms-law, nodal-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTB7AJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hi!

My question is if I(2) is a current that runs from Node 1 to Node 2 then the expression of I(2) as a function of I(A), I(B), R1, R2 and R3 is: I(2) = (I(A)*R1 - I(B)*R3)/R2. Right? Because that's how I always calculate currents going from node a to node b. A mix of Node-Voltage method and Ohm's law. However, the correct answer is not my answer it is I(2) = (I(A)*R1 - I(B)*R3)/(R1 + R2 + R3). Can someone kindly explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the right answer is that if \$I_2=\frac{V_1-V_2}{R_2}\$ then \$I_2=\frac{I_A\,\cdot\, R_1-I_B\,\cdot\, R_3}{R_1+R_2+R_3}\$.

You can convert \$I_A\$ and \$R_1\$ to their Thevenin equivalent voltage source of \$V_{_{\text{TH}_\text{A}}}=I_A\cdot R_1 \$ and it's Thevenin equivalent source resistance of \$R_1\$.

You can convert \$I_B\$ and \$R_3\$ to their Thevenin equivalent voltage source of \$V_{_{\text{TH}_\text{B}}}=I_B\cdot R_3 \$ and it's Thevenin equivalent source resistance of \$R_3\$.

This makes a series chain:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDDKgH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Consequently, it's obvious that \$I_2=\frac{I_A\,\cdot\, R_1-I_B\,\cdot\, R_3}{R_1+R_2+R_3}\$.

### Added KCL approach

Using SymPy/Sage/Python (all free to use and download) find:

```
eq1 = Eq( v1/r1 + v1/r2, v2/r2 + ia )
eq2 = Eq( v2/r2 + v2/r3, v1/r2 + ib )
ans = solve( [ eq1, eq2 ], [ v1, v2 ] )
simplify( ( ans[v1] - ans[v2] ) / r2 )
(ia*r1 - ib*r3)/(r1 + r2 + r3)
```

As you can see, this is the same result.

There are a number of approaches to a problem like this. All of them should get you to the same point, when applied correctly.

Note that the Norton-to-Thevenin conversion got to the exact same place as KCL. This is as it should be.

Comment: Thanks or your quick response! I did not apply Thevenin's equivalent, because I solved it with KCL and KVL around the middle mesh. And that's how I got the correct answer I wrote. You can do it in different ways! I have a little hard time calculating R(Thevenin) therefore I try to calculate I(Short) and V(Thevenin) first. It's not obvious that they are in series due to the neighbouring meshes.

Comment: @DiodeLight97 I'll add the KCL approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very useful! :)

Answer (score 0):

The current I(2) = (Vnode1-Vnode2)/R2

Your equation is incorrect because the Vnode1 is not equal to I(A)*R1 because the current flowing through R1 is not equal to I(A). Some current will get diverted into resistor R2 also.

Likewise, Vnode2 is not equal to I(B)*R3

Comment: I understand now! Thanks!